# Using https with socket.io 1.0.6 and getting an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, socket.io

I've been using https with socket.io on version 0.9 and below successfully for years.  I went to upgrade to the new 1.0 version and I'm getting an SSL error.  Here is the server-side node.js code to start the socket server:

```
var options = {};
options.key = fs.readFileSync('certs/ssh.key');
options.cert = fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.key'); //I've also tried using the property 'certificate' instead of 'cert'
var io = require('socket.io').listen(9091,options);
```

The connection works fine over standard http but https is giving me the error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I know that all certificate file references are good.  There seems to be no documentation on how to implement https socket.io connections on version 1.0, so I'm at a loss.  Any help is much appreciated.